# \setstretch and fixme package. How to reset stretch to 1 for fixmes?

Tags: line-spacing, setspace, fixme

I am using

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}
\usepackage[status=draft,layout=margin]{fixme}
```

in my document preamble. The notes are therefore also set with 1.5 stretch. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 15):

You can use the faces feature for this purpose, see section "3.9 Faces" of the
[documentation of package `fixme`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fixme/fixme.pdf).

In your case you are using margin notes, thus `\singlespacing` can be added to `marginface`, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}
\usepackage[status=draft,layout=margin]{fixme}

\fxsetup{marginface=\singlespacing}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \fxnote{
    Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi.
    Morbi auctor lorem non justo.  Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis
    vitae, ultricies et, tellus.}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]